# pg_dump --clean fails depending on --format

Tags: postgresql, alpine-linux, pg-dump

Taking a database dump with `pg_dump --clean` by default dumps a plain .sql file.  Restoring it works fine.

```
pg_dump --clean > dump.sql  
psql < dump.sql
```

However when supplying the `--format=t` flag to pg_dump, then extracting the file using tar, the restore fails.

```
pg_dump --clean  --format=t > dump.tar  
[toc.dat, nnnn.dat, and restore.sql extracted]  
tar -xvf dump.tar  
psql < restore.sql
```

With various

> ERROR:  could not open file "$$PATH$$/1234.dat" for reading: No such file or directory
>
> constraint for relation already exists
>
> relation already exists
>
> multiple primary keys for table

What's different when saving as tar?

Comment: Notes:  1234.dat matches a file extracted.  Running in a  alpine:3.10.2 container, talking to a postgres:10.4 container.  postgresql-client=11.5-r1.  tar=(busybox) 1.30.1

Comment: `--clean` makes only sense for SQL dumps.

Answer (score 1):

You get much the same thing without --clean (indeed, tar format doesn't honor it at all).  Tar format just isn't very convenient to use, you should probably use something else.

See the first few lines of the restore.sql

> ```
> --
> -- NOTE:
> --
> -- File paths need to be edited. Search for $$PATH$$ and
> -- replace it with the path to the directory containing
> -- the extracted data files.
> ```

Based on the error message, you haven't done that.

Answer (score 0):

The `--clean` option is only meaningful for the plain-text format. For the archive formats, you [have to use pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pgdump.html#Options).

`--format` isn't just changing the file format returned, but the type of backup.